# Merging Google spreadsheet range values with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Yes I know that this is replicating `=concat` functionality, but I have a need in a Google Spreadsheet App Script project to put a merge of ranges into a button.

```
 [ [ [ 'Joe Smith' ],
    [ 'Joe Johnson' ],
    [ '' ],
    [ 'Joe Jensen' ] ],
  [ [ '(479)123-4567' ],
    [ '' ],
    [ '(479) 321-1234' ],
    [ '479-987-0987' ] ] ]
```

The above is the array representation of two ranges.  Imagine I wanted to merge them into a single new column, with the values space separated, like...

```
  [ [ 'Joe Smith (479)123-4567' ],
    [ 'Joe Johnson ' ],
    [ '(479) 321-1234' ],
    [ 'Joe Jensen 479-987-0987' ],
    [ ' (479)123-4567' ] ]
```

(cleaning up errant spaces for nulls in previous or trailing columns is relatively simple)

What's the most efficient way to do this and account for *N* number of selected column ranges in Apps Script?

It seems like a needless waste of memory to put what might be thousands or tens of thousands of values into an intermediate array and then loop/merge that.

Is there an easier way I'm missing?

Code leading up to this...

```
let sel = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
// ...
lastCol = null;
firstCol = null;
if (sel.length == 1) {
    lastCol = spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastColumn();
    firstCol = (lastCol - spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns() + 1);
} else {
    lastCol = spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastColumn();
    firstCol = (lastCol - sel.length + 1);
};
let arr = [];
arr.push(firstCol);
arr.push(lastCol);
let colArray = missingNumbers(arr).concat(arr).sort();
console.log(colArray);
let range = spreadsheet.getRange(colArray[0], 1, 1, colArray.length).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).activate();
```

So basically I'm at an array of ranges, or an array of range values in nested lists if that's the best way.

As you can see I am force-selecting the useful data range, so the columns/rows will always be symmetrical.  The if/else on the range selector is just to account for whether the user has drag-selected a single multi-column range, or selected multiple columns with ctrl + click.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your sample values and your script and your expected result. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: I need to simulate `=CONCAT` functionality on a range of cells in app script.  In other words, to mass-concat selected columns' values into a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.map()`, `Array.flat()` and `Array.join()`, like this:

```js
  const ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  const values = ranges.map(range => range.getDisplayValues()).flat();
  const result = values.map(row => row.join(' '));
  console.log(result);
```